# Change the permissions for an existing user in hdfs on linux

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and I've run across an issue I'm not sure how to solve.

I have two existing HDFS users: one called hdfs and one called user1. When I write a file to HDFS as user1, both users can see and delete the files. However if I add the file as the user hdfs, user1 throws a file not found error when I try to use it. Why would one user be able to edit a file while the other can't? Is there anything I can do to allow user1 to also be able to edit the file?

Here are the permissions for the users:

```
hdfs  = drwxr-xr-x
user1 = drwxrwxr-x
```

I am running HDFS as part of OpenJDK 1.8 on CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hdfs user is a super user, so whenever you copy a file as `hdfs`, other uses cannot see. if you want to see those file you have to execute command as like below

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -cat /path/`

user1 is a normal user, so whenever you copy a file as `user1`, hdfs user can have access to those files

yes, there is command like below to change groups, users, owners, etc

```
hdfs dfs chgrp
hdfs dfs chmod
hdfs dfs chown
```

Answer (score 2):

hdfs is [super-user](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User) who is not restricted by permission checks and can particularly access files of other users, like user1

`chmod` can be done as follows: `hdfs dfs -chmod XXX /dir`

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is the super-user here so it has access to all the files but if you want to see the file which has user and group as hdfs through user1 then you can't able to see directly.

Firstly you need to change the user and group of that file then only you can able to see that file.

For changing the owner and group of that file use the below commands :-

hadoop fs -chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] URI [URI ]