# Dockerfile to give permissions to hdfs

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, dockerfile, hdfs

I have a dockerfile that runs everything I want in my container. In this case I want to run a spark code and in the dockerfile I give spark permission to write in a certain directory.

Now, I also wanted spark to be allowed to run on hdfs. For this I am using a "chown -R" as I did in other cases, but for HDFS it does not work.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-slim
COPY ./ /test
WORKDIR /teste
RUN mvn -e install
RUN apt-get update && \
 ...
chown -R spark:spark /usr/spark* && \
chown -R spark:spark hdfs://localhost:8020/user/admin*

USER spark
WORKDIR /opt/spark
```

This way I can write a file in the directory "/usr/spark" but I can't in hdfs. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Can't I do the same for HDFS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the permissions for an existing user in hdfs on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379109/change-the-permissions-for-an-existing-user-in-hdfs-on-linux)

Comment: does not answer because here are commands to put on the command line, and I wanted to put it in my Dockerfile file, to give spark permission to write/put file on HDFS

Comment: It does answer your case. Your problem is you did not know the command and it suggests the command.

Answer (score 0):

`chown` itself is for local files

You want `hadoop fs chown` for HDFS files.

However, you should really do that outside of the container build process because `localhost:8020` is the container itself, and is not an accessible  HDFS location

Comment: I work everything within a cluster. When I send a talend Big Data file to HDFS, he puts the file there. However, when I want this spark code to save me a file in that same place, I no longer have permissions, that's why I remembered to give those permissions in the Dockerfile

Comment: Sure... But `localhost` is the Java container itself, not HDFS. You should run your Spark code as the user that has permissions to the parent folder not all users that are prefxed by `admin`